# drag and drop image like gmail

Tags: drag-and-drop, gmail

how gmail does drag and drop of images. Many searches point to Gear. But it seems it should be installed in browser. But gmail does this with Gear installed in the client side. Could anyone explain it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 File API

http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/

Comment: what about client browsers that dont have HTML5. How to do this in those browsers.